# SQL query giving an incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select COUNT(*) as 'Number'
From image
WHERE (image.current_phase = 'aggregation' AND (image.raw_filename REGEXP '%gordonpho%back%$'))
```

The above SQL query is giving me an incorrect syntax error. I want to get the number of rows from the table `image` where the column `image.current_phase` has aggregation as text. Also the column `image.raw_filename` ends with '%gordonpho%back%'.

Can anybody see the syntax error in my statement?

Comment: If you're truly using regular expression syntax there, I doubt `%` is what you want.

Comment: REGEXP  isn't valid in TSQL. Use CLR or `LIKE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REGEXP` isn't valid in T-SQL, but you don't need it anyway since your "regular expression" would be the same using `LIKE` anyway:

```
Select COUNT(*) as 'Number'
From image
WHERE (image.current_phase = 'aggregation'
       AND (image.raw_filename LIKE '%gordonpho%back%')
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions natively. Try using LIKE:

```
Select COUNT(*) as 'Number'
From image
WHERE (image.current_phase = 'aggregation' 
    AND (image.raw_filename LIKE '%gordonpho%back%'))
```

For times where you really need/want to use regular expressions, you'd have to do it via SQLCLR support (.NET code).

Answer (score -1):

It's possible in your SQL implementation that `image` is a reserved word. Try quoting it with backticks (MySQL), square brackets `[]` (MSSQL) or double quotes `"` (most others).

Also, the `%`s in `'%gordonpho%back%$'` aren't treated as wildcards in regular expressions. Try replacing the literal with:

```
'.*gordonpho.*back.*$'
```

Comment: Sorry, where in that post does it say it's for SQL server? Oh yeah, a tag. Good grief.